# increasing the volume of several mp3 files via lame

Tags: linux, bash, console, lame

it's already known that

```
lame --scale N song.mp3 loud_song.mp3
```

where N is the scale number.

well, I want to apply in every mp3 file in a folder, and preserve the name of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tmpfile=~/.deleteme.mp3
MyExit() { rm -f "$tmpfile"; }
trap MyExit EXIT

for f in *.mp3
do
    lame --scale 2 "$f" "$tmpfile" && mv "$tmpfile" "$f"
done
```